# WPF XAML Designer 'Exception Cannot read Page properties because it is not in a tree with Window as its root.'

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am creating a WPF page that inherits from a base page class and has a type argument of the view model. The code compiles and runs fine however the designer states there is an exception throw.

The code:

```
<local:BasePage x:TypeArguments="local:SplashScreenViewModel" x:Class="CommentatorScreen.SplashScreen"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CommentatorScreen"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
  Title="SplashScreen">

    <Grid>
        <Button Command="{Binding TestCommand}" Content="I am a button" />
    </Grid>
</local:BasePage>
```

Exception:

[image]

I'm not sure if this is related to the problem but if I remove the Type Argument and just have it inherit from the base page, it still complies but I get the error:

> The name "BasePage" doesn't not exist in the namespace 'clr-namescape:CommentatorScreen'.

And reverting back to a normal page allows the designer works fine.
[image]

```
<Page x:Class="CommentatorScreen.SplashScreen"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CommentatorScreen"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
  Title="SplashScreen">

<Grid Background="White">
    <Button Command="{Binding TestCommand}" Content="I am a button" />
</Grid>
```

I have tried the usual clean the solution, rebuilding the solution, restarting Visual Studio, updating Visual Studio.

Any help would be appreciated.

BasePage:

```
namespace CommentatorScreen
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class for basic page functions
    /// </summary>
    public class BasePage<VM>: Page
        where VM : BaseViewModel, new()
    {
        #region Privates

        /// <summary>
        /// Pages view model
        /// </summary>
        private VM viewModel;

        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// View model for the page
        /// </summary>
        public VM ViewModel
        {
            get { return viewModel; }
            set
            {
                // If no change
                if (viewModel == value)
                {
                    return;
                }

                // Update the view model
                viewModel = value;

                // Set data context
                DataContext = viewModel;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Constuctor

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public BasePage()
        {
            //Create a default view model
            ViewModel = new VM();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Splash screen:

```
namespace CommentatorScreen
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for SplashScreen.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class SplashScreen : BasePage<SplashScreenViewModel>
    {
        public SplashScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show code behind of SplashScreen?

Comment: @o_w  Ive done that now

Comment: Why do you hold the VM inside your page? usually the goal is to keep them separate, so they won't have direct reference to each other.

Answer (score 0):

XAML designer in the VS is not WYSIWYG. Other words, the XAML markup that you enter in XAML code editor is not exactly what is displayed in XAML graphical editor.

When you open XAML file in the editor, VS generates all the environment to support displaying graphically the markup you enter. You may try to search for exact files generated (including cached XAML files), see:

C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_7fec07a1\Designer\Cache\**

VS supports live preview feature, meaning it can display the markup you enter even if your project is not compiled yet. If you’re using custom base classes – while generating preview, base class may not be available. The designer removes from your code some parts to allow visualizing your markup.

I think then you’ll have a look what VS generates (the designer cache files), you will catch the idea.

Comment: I've checked out the files you mentioned. I found a '16.0_8a155c38\Designer\Cache\11225518934x64DA\Pages\~vs]~297~SplashScreen.xaml'
Which has the starting tag as 
'<_0:Object'

Comment: For a test purpose, can you put your BasePage class in the separate assembly? To simplify the test, keep it without generic argument. Next, reference this assembly in the project where your SplashScreen / XAML exists.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by a separate assembly? A new project within the solution?

Comment: Correct, new project within solution or in separate solution. The goal is to check if there is difference if at design time the XAML designer has access to already compiled/available base type.

Comment: I think I've transferred everything correctly over but I get: 'BasePage does not exist in the namescape 'clr-namespace:WpfApp1;assembly=WpfApp1' and it does not complie

Comment: You should create library project rather than WpfApp project. Next, make sure that both - xaml-containing project and library project targets exactly the same version of .net.